# how to check onRadioButtonClicked value when I get the value from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, radio-button

how to check onRadioButtonClicked value when I get the value from firebase?

in my firebase data, I used this way to get the value `chk_country = snapshot.child("country").getValue().toString();`

but how can I set value? I mean, if the user set country value is Australia that the R.id.australia is checked, opposite if the user set country is Taiwan that the R.id.taiwan is checked.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                chk_country = snapshot.child("country").getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        
        boolean isSelected = ((AppCompatRadioButton)view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.australia:
                if(isSelected){
                    australia.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    taiwan.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    type = "Australia";
                }
                break;
            case R.id.taiwan:
                if(isSelected){
                    taiwan.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    australia.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    type = "Taiwan";
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/australia"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/australia"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/radio_button_left_selector"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/taiwan"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/taiwan"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/radio_button_right_selector"
                    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly would you like to select/check? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo Because I can't get the value, how could I call onRadioButtonClicked on onCreate ?

Comment: I see you already solved the issue, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use radio1.setChecked(true); and radio2.setChecked(false); for the other value